# Optimizing several queries with GROUP BY that starts with the same fields

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Database is MySQL. For example : I have one table and several SELECT queries with GROUP BY :

```
SELECT
    MIN(price)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY
    field1, field2, field3, field4;

SELECT
    MIN(price)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY
    field1, field2, field3, field5;

SELECT
    MIN(price)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY
    field1, field2, field3, field6;
```

All queries performs grouping by field1, field2, field3. Is there any way to optimize or cache the same operations ?

Comment: but all of them contain extra column, that makes unable to reach what you are trying to do

Comment: post your `table` schema and sample of data stored, I guess you should redesign the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do sounds simple but it actually only makes sense from a "code conservation" perspective (meaning less code, not really less work for the database).  In reality, "GROUP BY field1, field2, field3" is actually a subset of what's returned by "GROUP BY field1, field2, field3, field4".  Let me illustrate with a data set:

```
price | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4
------|--------|--------|--------|-------
1.00  |    1   |   1    |   1    |   1   
1.50  |    1   |   1    |   1    |   2   
2.00  |    1   |   1    |   2    |   3   
3.00  |    1   |   1    |   2    |   3
```

"GROUP BY field1, field2, field3" returns:

```
min_price | field1 | field2 | field3 
----------|--------|--------|--------
   1.00   |    1   |   1    |   1    
   2.00   |    1   |   1    |   2
```

"GROUP BY field1, field2, field3, field4" returns *more* rows:

```
min_price | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4
----------|--------|--------|--------|-------
   1.00   |    1   |   1    |   1    |   1   
   1.50   |    1   |   1    |   1    |   2   
   2.00   |    1   |   1    |   2    |   3
```

As you can see, you cannot somehow reuse the first group by statement to get the second result set.

If performance is your question, @deadzone's suggestion of a materialized view is a good one.  You could create a materialized view on a group by of *all* the fields if it would pair down the rows some (GROUP BY field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6).  Other than that, you'll just need to ensure that each query is optimized.

If code conservation is your concern, MySQL doesn't give you a lot of options because it doesn't support dynamic SQL.  SQL is a language where the best option is all too often writing more code (insert inner programmer **sigh**).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to improve the performance of your select queries that use aggregated data, I'd suggest looking into one or more [Materialized Views](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views).  This is (under the covers) somewhat similar to having additional tables.  But they are views on the source table and will need to be refreshed periodically.  And although creating/refreshing the MV's might not be very fast, querying them for these queries should provide significant performance gains.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches come to mind:

1) Use [temporary table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html). Group by all 6 fields and save intermediary result in a temporary table, then group further three times to get the final results.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl_name
SELECT
    field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6
    ,MIN(price) AS price
FROM table
GROUP BY
    field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6;


SELECT
    MIN(price)
FROM temp_tbl_name
GROUP BY
    field1, field2, field3, field4;

SELECT
    MIN(price)
FROM temp_tbl_name
GROUP BY
    field1, field2, field3, field5;

SELECT
    MIN(price)
FROM temp_tbl_name
GROUP BY
    field1, field2, field3, field6;


-- temp table would be dropped automatically, so often explicit DROP is not needed
DROP TABLE temp_tbl_name;
```

> A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current session, and is
>   dropped automatically when the session is closed.

This approach makes sense, if the first aggregation by all 6 fields significantly reduces the number of rows.

2) Consider using [`GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

```
SELECT
    field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6
    ,MIN(price)
FROM table
GROUP BY
    field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6
WITH ROLLUP;
```

This single query will produce all variants of grouping the fields, not just the three that you are after, so you'll need to filter the result further.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way to process `GROUP BY` is when an index is used to directly retrieve the grouping columns.

if your query is over a single table and  only MIN() or MAX() aggregate functions used in the select, you'd better create a multi-columns index.

try this:

```
create index index_name1 on your_table(field1, field2, field3, field4);
create index index_name2 on your_table(field1, field2, field3, field5);
create index index_name3 on your_table(field1, field2, field3, field6);
```

[GROUP BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:**

```
create index cov_index on table (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, price);
```

**Explanation**

There's not much of any way to shrink the code required to share work among these queries.

But there is a way to make the queries more efficient. It's called a [covering index](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727). It's an index containing all the columns the MySQL query engine needs to satisfy your queries.

To optimize your first query, we would need these columns in the index.

```
  field1, field2, field3, field4, price
```

The BTREE style indexes used in MySQL are inherently sorted in order. So the query engine can satisfy this `MAX(price) ... GROUP BY all the rest` query by romping through the index in order doing an operation known as a [loose index scan](http://www.arubin.org/blog/2010/11/18/loose-index-scan-vs-covered-indexes-in-mysql/).  This works because the index contains, *in order,* all the columns mentioned in `GROUP BY` and then the column being summarized. Loose index scans can be astonishingly fast.

But you also want `GROUP BY field1, field2, field3, field5` and some other variants of your query. If you want all your variant queries to be satisfied with loose index scans, you'll need a separate covering index for each query. That's a lot of indexes.

But if you are willing for some queries to be satisfied by full index scans rather than loose index scans, you can put more columns in your covering index, so all the fields are mentioned. The first three fields need to stay in order.

```
field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, price
```

is the index you'll need. Your first query can still use a loose index scan. The rest will still exploit the partial ordering of the index.

There is a disadvantage to indexes, of course: they slow insertions and updates.

Comment: index on `field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, price` is not applicable if the query has `GROUP BY field1, field2, field3, field5`, because the columns are not a leftmost prefix.

Comment: @LFJ the index can still be used for a tight index scan to satisfy the query. You're right that it won't work for a loose index scan.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the GROUP BY field1,2,3 in a SUBQUERY to minimize the Resultset.

Set the SUBQUERY Chache on;

```
SET optimizer_switch='subquery_cache=on';

SELECT
    id,
    MIN(price)
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        MIN(price)
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY
        field1, field2, field3
) AS tmp
GROUP BY
    field1, field2, field3, field4;


SELECT
    id,
    MIN(price)
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        MIN(price)
    FROM `table`
    GROUP BY
        field1, field2, field3
) AS tmp
GROUP BY
    field1, field2, field3, field5;
```

Comment: This doesn't really minimize the result set because you'll also have to group by the id.  Caching a subquery may make it a little faster though...

Comment: @Daniel Grosskopf  Sorry, the Question wars:
All queries performs grouping by field1, field2, field3. Is there any way to **optimize or cache** the same operations ?

Comment: This query will never run. How are you going to group by `field5` in your outer query if it's not returned by your `tmp` Derived Table?

Comment: you right. The inne Query must deliver all fields you nied in the outer query. Sorry